# Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ in a group $G$. If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $a^m$ has order $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

> Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ in a group $G$.
>
> If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $a^m$ has order $n$.

Assume $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, and that $a^m$ does not have order $n$. Say it has order $k$, so that $(a^m)^k=e$.

Since the order of $a$ is $n$, $$e=a^n=(a^m)^k$$

So, $mk \equiv 0 \pmod n$, and therefore $n \mid mk$

Since $n$ is a factor of $mk$, and since $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime, $n$ must be a factor of $k$ only.

From the premise of my proof, I should be coming up with some sort of contradiction involving: $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime; but I can't come up with this.

Comment: For reference, this is Pinter 10.G.1.

Comment: Just drop the assumption that $a^m$ does not have order $n$. Then you don't need to use contradiction. You already proved that $n|k$. Under this condition, it is trivial to prove that $k=n$ (just calculate $(a^m)^n$).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You have $n$ is a factor of $k$. Then, $n \mid k \Rightarrow k \geq n$. Is there a contradiction to be found here?

Comment: If $n$ is a factor of $k$, then $k=nq$. I can't see a contradiction here.

Comment: The order of $a^m$ can be strictly greater than the order of $a$? The contradiction comes from assuming that $o(a^m) \neq o(a)$, not $\gcd(m,n) = 1$.

Comment: I thought using a proof by contradiction involved assuming P and (not Q), and arriving at (not P). Thus arriving at P and (not P), a contradiction.

Comment: Any contradiction suffices. I see you are trying to arrive at the specific contradiction $P \land \lnot P$. That works, but if $P \land \lnot Q \Rightarrow 1 = 0$ (i.e. any contradiction) that is still a valid proof by contradiction.

Comment: It may be helpful to note that arriving at any contradiction allows you to state that anything is true ([Principle of explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)), so $1 = 0 \Rightarrow P \land \lnot P$, if you are that stubborn about showing $P \land \lnot P$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $b=a^m$ with order $k$.

First note $b^n=a^{mn}=(a^n)^m=e$, so $k|n$.

On the other hand, $e=b^k=a^{mk}$, so $n|mk$. But since $m,n$ are relatively prime, we have $n|k$.

Hence $k=n$

Comment: If you are assuming $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime and $a^m$ has order $k$, shouldn't you be arriving at the conclusion that $n$ and $m$ are not relatively prime? Thus arriving at a contradiction.

Comment: @JohannFranklin Why? I don't understand how you get the contradiction.

Comment: That's what I am trying to find.  I thought if we assumed $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime and $a^m$ does not have order n, we should arrive at $n$ and $m$ are not relatively prime and thus we have a contradiction.

Comment: @JohannFranklin First you don't need to find a contradiction. Note $a|b, b|a \implies a=b$. So by your argument, you know $n|k$, and you can find $k|n$ as I have written above. So this implies $k=n$.

Comment: In the second line of your argument, why does $k \mid n$?

Comment: @JohannFranklin We know the order of an element the order $k=|a|=\text{min}\{k\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}|a^k=e\}$. If $a^n=e$, by division algorithm of integer, we can know $\exists q,r \in \mathbb{Z},0\leq r<k$, s.t. $n=qk+r$. If $r\neq 0$, we get $a^r=e$, which contradicts the smallest property of the order.

Comment: The order of $a$ is not k. The order of $a$ is n.  We are assuming the order of $a^m$ is k.

Comment: @JohannFranklin You are right, but in the second line, we have shown $(a^m)^n=e$, which means $k|n$ by the reason I stated above.

Comment: $a$ has order $n$ is given.  Assume gcd(n,m)=1 and $a^m$ does not have order n, so that $(a^m)^n$ does not equal $e$. But $(a^m)^n=(a^n)^m=e^m=e$. Isn't that a contradiction in itself? Can we do this, that is, not use the assumption that gcd(m,n)=1?

Answer (score 0):

This is 10.G.1 from Pinter:

> If `m` and `n` are relatively prime then `a^m` has order `n`.
>
> (HINT: If `a^(mk) = e`, use 10.T5 and explain why `n` must be a factor
>   of `k`.)

He suggests that we use 10.T5:

> Suppose an element `a` in a group has order `n`.
>
> Then `a^t = e` iff `t` is a multiple of `n` ("`t` is a multiple of `n`"
>   means that `t = nq` for some integer `q`).

The proof:

```
ord(a) = n                  (1)

gcd(m,n) = 1                (5)

(a^m)^n
(a^n)^m
e^m
e
```

Thus:

```
(a^m)^n = e
```

If `n` is the lowest number such that the above is true, then `n` is the order of `a^m`.

Let's check to see if there is a lower number.

Suppose there is a number `k` such that:

```
k < n                       (3)

(a^m)^k = e
```

Then we have:

```
a^(mk) = e                  (2)
```

By 10.T5 with (1) and (2):

```
n | mk
```

Due to (5), `n` does not divide `m`. So it must divide `k`:

```
n | k                   (4)
```

(4) contradicts (3) therefore there is no such number `k`.

Therefore `n` is the minimum value such that:

```
(a^m)^n = e
```

I.e.

```
ord(a^m) = e
```